# masked textbox in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox

I want add to my Windows phone app masked textbox, are there ready-made control for this?
In silverlight  windows phone version property "mask" is disabled.

Comment: If you just need to do a password there is the PasswordBox class. For full masked textbox support I don't know of any but it does look like Telerik is considering adding that control to their control suite possibly as soon as Q1 this year: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/windows-phone/general-discussions/masked-textbox.aspx#1920605

Comment: I need to set a input mask to textbox, for example for email input or post code input. For checking correctly input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBoxInputRegexFilterBehavior is answer at my question. [Windows Phone 7 Silverlight: Behaviors for TextBox](http://outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/308)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the standard PasswordBox control. It gives you the option to add which character will serve as the masking character. In the following example '^' is used to mask your text input.

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChar="^" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,408,0,0"   Name="passwordBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />
```